# Python flask jinja template hyperlink tag

Tags: python, flask

[Image for python part](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EUney.png)
[Image for html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mYpMW.png)

Comment: Hi Sam Thapa, a lot of info is missing here! could you add it all the data? I mean, the rest of the python code, the functions, where is redirecting you? and all the code and data you think that could help others to understand your situation. THanks!

Comment: Could you show us the python code? I believe comes with a `redirect` function if I'm not mistaken...

Comment: @DamianLattenero i have added addtional info

Comment: @mangoHero1 i have added addtional info

Comment: @SamThapa fantastic, and now, the best way is to copy the python code, and past it in the question, image are not needed, but also, you have to write by hand some text explaining your problems, and what you tried, your attempts, and what it must do, and what returns

Comment: Deindent your `return render_template()` code, that might be the issue